# Getting generated view with MVC on Docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, model-view-controller, .net-core

I have a dotnet core application with authorization. Because company policy does not allow to store Bearer tokens on the front-end, I want to run it through an MVC Controller. However, I am running a SPA with Vue.js which is generated. So I have to return the generated index.cshtml from the Controller. This works locally in Kestrel, but once I deploy it to a Docker container it doesn't work anymore -- I suppose it has something to do with the way MVC expects files to be somewhere and this doesn't match how Docker handles it.

I've tried various ways to find the file on the pod. The app runs standard in /app; and the SPA was initially deployed to /app/wwwroot. I couldn't find a way to make the MVC Controller read from that folder. I changed the vue.js webpack to create an Index.cshtml and all required assets under /app/View/[ControllerName] but that didn't work either.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime

EXPOSE 80

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy files from the artifact staging folder on agent
COPY <ProjectName>/out .

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install ca-certificates -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ADD certificate.crt
ADD certificate2.crt
ADD certificate3.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<ProjectName>.dll"]
```

Expected result: the SPA loads.
Actual results: often MVC errors that it couldn't find the index.cshtml file in various locations. And it's always looking at the wrong locations, even though I'm trying to point it in the right direction. That was with trying to point at the vue.js under /app/wwwroot; with the SPA being generated under /Views/[ControllerName] it appears the buildserver isn't building it correctly to place it there and other strange things happen. At one time, apparently, it generated a HomeController; which the project doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fidgeting around and I've ended up simply grabbing the generated file and return that as a response.

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    try
    {
        var fileStream = new FileStream("/app/wwwroot/index.html", FileMode.Open);
        return File(fileStream, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Kon /app/wwwroot/index.html niet openen", ex);
    }  

    return StatusCode(500);
 }
```